# Ability to delete really old, negative-voted, irrelevant questions

Tags: feature-request, down-votes, deleted-questions, old-questions

I have a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3570789/how-do-you-make-an-animated-jpg) I asked a while ago that has since been downvoted a bunch (even though I believe it's a particularly interesting question, but that's beside the point). I'd like to delete it, as the image I was referencing no longer exists, rendering the whole question irrelevant unless I can find another like it.

Unfortunately I can't delete it because it has answers. There should be some way to handle this situation, although I don't presume to know what it should be.

If a question is particularly old and has a negative score, shouldn't the OP be able to delete that question? It's obviously not useful...

Comment: Downvoted doesn't mean not helpful. [Here's a shady question with a very helpful answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905734/how-to-send-100-000-emails-weekly)

Comment: yeah, but i want to delete the question, and i'm still getting hit with downvotes from it. shouldn't i be able to delete my own question?

Comment: Well... that isn't fair to those who answered it is it? Especially if they are still gaining upvotes for it. That said, there's one option left. But I don't feel comfortable recommending it because it is considered abusive and you will likely get your account suspended if you do it too often.

Comment: I don't want to do anything shady, and I don't think that people who answered and received upvotes should lose their rep. I just want the question removed from public view.

Comment: Just to note, most of them *wouldn't* lose their reputation for this being deleted. But I do feel this question *is* off-topic and should be deleted eventually (I've voted to close it).

Comment: Since you're a high-rep user, then I'll mention it. But the moderators have warned that if you do it too many times, you'll be suspended. That option is to exercise your CC-wiki rights to request for disassociation of the post from your account. By law, SE is required to honor your request. But doing so to escape downvotes is considered abusive.

Comment: yea i don't even know how to do that and that seems like a big hassle. I was just hoping for something that could "remove from public" or "remove from search results"

Comment: You'd do that by emailing the team. In any case, that question has almost 8k views. It's a search engine target. So I not sure if deleting it is gonna do the internet any good. It might be better to just try to fix it up.

Comment: Looks like a mod agreed to delete it. You're good to go. :)

Answer (score 10):

In the general case, even when your question is bad, the answers might be where the value is. So no, you should not be able to just delete it imo. Though you could flag for moderator attention and ask them to have a look. I can't say the specific question adds a whole lot to the site.